# How to ROLLUP a SUM over multiple columns on separate tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables from which I want to aggregate data using MySQL 5.7.

```
Projects
+------------+--------+------------------+
| project_id | org_id |       name       |
+------------+--------+------------------+
|          1 |      1 | Big Project      |
|          2 |      1 | Internal Project |
+------------+--------+------------------+

Tasks
+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+
|  task_id  | org_id |      name      | project_id |
+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+
|         1 |      1 | Check Work     |          1 |
|         2 |      1 | Fix Code       |          1 |
|         3 |      1 | Rebuild Office |          2 |
+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+

Resources
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| resource_id | org_id |  first_name | last_name |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |      1 | Alice       | Black     |
|           2 |      1 | Bob         | Smith     |
|           3 |      1 | Charlie     | White     |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+

Task_Details
+-------------+--------+---------+-------------+
| resource_id | org_id | task_id | total_hours |
+-------------+--------+---------+-------------+
|           1 |      1 |       1 |          12 |
|           2 |      1 |       1 |           4 |
|           3 |      1 |       1 |           8 |
|           2 |      1 |       2 |           4 |
|           3 |      1 |       2 |           4 |
|           1 |      1 |       3 |          16 |
+-------------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

I want to SUM the total_hours, GROUPing by task and project, while still showing the total_hours each employee has individually spent on a task. The output I'm looking for would be something like this

```
Desired Output
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|   project_name   |   task_name    | first_name | last_name | total_hours |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Alice      | Green     |          12 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Bob        | Smith     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Charlie    | Brown     |           8 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | NULL       | NULL      |          24 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | Bob        | Smith     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | Charlie    | Brown     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | NULL       | NULL      |           8 |
| Big Project      | NULL           | NULL       | NULL      |          32 |
| Internal Project | Rebuild Office | Alice      | Green     |          16 |
| Internal Project | Rebuild Office | NULL       | NULL      |          16 |
| Internal Project | NULL           | NULL       | NULL      |          16 |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I've managed to create a query that JOINs the relevant tables together, and even managed to GROUP them by project_id, task_id and resource_id. However, adding a WITH ROLLUP statement to the end of my query causes it to fail even though it works without one.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
    t1.project_name,
    t1.task_name,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.last_name,
    SUM(t1.task_hours)
FROM (
   SELECT
        Projects.project_id,
        Projects.name AS project_name,
        Tasks.task_id,
        Tasks.name AS task_name,
        Resources.resource_id,
        Task_Details.total_hours AS task_hours
    FROM
        Projects
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        Tasks
    ON
        Projects.org_id = Tasks.org_id AND
        Projects.project_id = Tasks.project_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Task_Details
    ON
        Task_Details.org_id = Tasks.org_id AND
        Task_Details.task_id = Tasks.task_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Resources
    ON
        Resources.org_id = Task_Details.org_id AND
        Resources.resource_id = Task_Details.resource_id
    WHERE
        Projects.org_id = 1 
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        resource_id,
        first_name,
        last_name
    FROM
        Resources
    WHERE
        org_id = 1
) AS t2
ON
    t2.resource_id = t1.resource_id
GROUP BY
    t1.project_id,
    t1.task_id,
    t1.resource_id;
```

**How can I modify my query such that WITH ROLLUP works?**

My SQLFiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa931/1), but notably is for MySQL 5.6 rather than 5.7

Comment: Does it fail with an error? -> What does it say? Does it "fail" with an unexpected result set? -> What's the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the problem with your query is this: You select some columns which are not in the `GROUP BY`. That causes some non-sensical values in the columns `first_name`, `last_name`, `project_name` and `task_name`. However, the sum column is probably correct, isn't it?

This works for me:

```
SELECT p.name as project_name, 
    s1.task_name, 
    first_name,
    last_name, 
    s1.total_hours 
    FROM (
         SELECT 
         t.project_id, 
         t.name as task_name, 
         h.resource_id, 
         sum(h.total_hours) as total_hours 
         FROM Task_Details as h 
         JOIN Tasks as t ON (t.task_id=h.task_id) 
         GROUP BY t.project_id, t.name, h.resource_id WITH ROLLUP
      ) AS s1 
      LEFT JOIN Resources AS r ON (s1.resource_id=r.resource_id) 
      JOIN Projects AS p ON (p.project_id=s1.project_id);
```

The nested `SELECT` does the interesting work, it sums up the total_hours of every `resource_id`, every `task_name` and and every `project_id`. The nesting `SELECT` then collects the name of every resource and project.

OUTPUT:

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| project_name     | task_name      | first_name | last_name | total_hours |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Big Project      | NULL           | NULL       | NULL      |          32 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Alice      | Green     |          12 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | NULL       | NULL      |          24 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Bob        | Smith     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Check Work     | Charlie    | Brown     |           8 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | Bob        | Smith     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | Charlie    | Brown     |           4 |
| Big Project      | Fix Code       | NULL       | NULL      |           8 |
| Internal Project | NULL           | NULL       | NULL      |          16 |
| Internal Project | Rebuild Office | NULL       | NULL      |          16 |
| Internal Project | Rebuild Office | Alice      | Green     |          16 |
+------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking at the problem backwards, didn't think to get the sum first and then JOIN on that. Thank you